# Need Help: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get my code to give me information such as price of an item if I input the brand "Nike" or anything like that. However, I am getting the error code as the title. Please any help would be appreciated

```
clothing_brands = [
["544", "Jordan", "Shoes", 200],
["681", "Stussy", "Sweatshirt", 50],
["481", "Obey", "T-Shirt", 30],
["339", "North Face", "Jacket", 80],
["250", "Levis", "Jeans", 40],
["091", "Nike", "Socks", 10],
]

def findClothing(brand):
    found = False
    for brand in clothing_brands:
        if clothing_brands in brand[1]:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        return brand
    else:
        return None

def printBrand(brand):
    print ("\n~~~~Thrift Shop Brands:~~~~")
    print ("Item Number:", brand[0])
    print ("Brand Name:", brand[1])
    print ("Clothing Type:", brand[2])
    print ("Price:", brand[3])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("\n~~~Welcome to Macklemore's clothing Thrift Shop~~~~")
    print ("1) Add a brand you would like to see us carry")
    print ("2) What is the brand's clothing type?")
    print ("3) What is the price of a particular brand?")
    print ("4) What is a brand's information?")
    print ("5) Print everything we have in stock")
    print ("0) Exit")

    while True:
        option = input ("Please Select a Menu item.")

        if (option == "0"):
            break

        if (option == "1"):
            Item_number = input ("What is the Item Number?")
            Brand_name = input ("What is the name of the Brand?")
            Clothing_type = input ("What type of clothing is the Brand?")
            Price = input ("How much is the item?")
            brand = [Item_number, Brand_name, Clothing_type, Price]
            clothing_brands.append(brand)
            print ("Thank you for your input, We will begin searching to add that item into our inventory")
            print (Brand_name, Clothing_type, Price)
            print ("Come back in a couple of days to see if we have added the item")

        if (option == "2"):
            brand = input ("What is the brand you are looking for information on?")
            brand = findClothing(brand)
            if (brand != None):
                print ("The Clothing type of this brand is:", brand[2])

        if (option == "3"):
           brand = input ("What is the brand you are looking for information on?")
           brand = findClothing(brand)
           if (brand != None):
                print ("The Price of the brand is:", brand[3])

        if (option == "4"):
            brand = input ("What is the brand you are looking for information on?")
            brand = findClothing(brand)
            if (brand != None):
                printBrand (brand)
            else:
                print ("Sorry, we do not carry this brand. If you would like for us to search for this brand, Please try option 1!")

        if (option == "5"):
            for brand in clothing_brands:
                print (brand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findClothing` method does not use its input parameter (it's overwritten by the loop variable) and is instead using `if clothing_brands in brand[1]:` which makes no sense since `clothing_brands` is not even a string.

Fixing that fixes your error;

```
def findClothing(input_brand):
    found = False
    for brand in clothing_brands:
        if input_brand in brand[1]:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        return brand
    else:
        return None
```